# ValueError: object too deep for desired array [np.bincount]

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning

I have a dataset with three classes divided into training and testing; how can I calculate the number of occurrences of each class in training and testing?

```
def load_data():
        data=  [] #images are stored here
        labels=[] # extract the class label from the filename
        # convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays while scaling the pixel
        data = np.array(data) / 255.0
        labels = np.array(labels)
       
        labels = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(labels)
        labels = to_categorical(labels)

        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2)

    return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)
```

Shapes of x and y:

```
x_train shape (4415, 32, 32, 1)
x_test shape (1104, 32, 32, 1)
y_train shape (4415, 3)
y_test shape (1104, 3)
```

I'm trying to print numbers of instances in each class by using np.bincount

```
print('Training:', np.bincount(y_train) / float(len(y_train)) * 100.0)
print('Test:', np.bincount(y_test) / float(len(y_test)) * 100.0)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Note:
I can print them if I don't convert labels to categorical `"labels = to_categorical(labels)"` but it's required for my mode.

Comment: Is that `to_categorical` from `keras`?

Comment: @BenReiniger yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already one-hot encoded, you can just take the columnwise sums.  The output of `keras.utils.to_categorical` is a numpy array, so `y_train.sum(axis=0)` should do it, providing an array of the counts.